# reactive 4 2 0 Will Repeat and FirstAsync work together?

Tags: reactive

Why do I not get any results register value and a high CPU usage on one of these but not the other?

```
Int32 __Register = Observable.Return(100).Repeat().FirstAsync().Wait();

Int32 __Register2 = Observable.Return(100).Delay(dueTime: TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1))
.Repeat().FirstAsync().Wait();
```

Answer (score 0):

Observable.Repeat(100).FirstAsync().Wait
works
DO I need more superfluous operators in here? How about Amb Switc

Comment: new List<Int32> { 999 }
                .ToObservable()
                .Repeat()
                .FirstAsync()
                .Wait();

            Observable.Return(999)
                .Repeat()
                .FirstAsync()
                .Wait();

Comment: Another example.  Is there some problem with FirstAsync trying to Subscribe to cold observable across the Repeat barrier?

Comment: Observable.Empty<Int32>().Append(1).Repeat().FirstAsync().ToTask()